# sum tabel based on certain content

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sum, sql-order-by

```
select
om.orderno,
od.product,
od.preorderqty,
(od.preorderqty * od.nto) as preordernet
from OrderMaster om
join OrderDetail od on od.orderid = om.id
and ((od.prodcode like '100-%') or (od.prodcode like '200-%'))
order by om.orderno,sod.prodcode
```

**Current result:**

```
ORDERNO PRODUCT PREORDERQTY PREORDERNET 
1000    100-A   2           200
1000    100-B   2           300
1000    100-C   1           450
2000    100-A   3           300
2000    100-B   1           150
2000    200-A   2           900
3000    200-A   1           450
```

**I would need help getting a script that:**

- Sums the orders based on specific content
- Orders can contain products beginning with 300- etc.

**Expected result:**

```
ORDERNO PRODUCT PREORDERQTY PREORDERNET ORDERNET
1000    100-A   2           200         950
1000    100-B   2           300         950
1000    100-C   1           450         950
2000    100-A   3           300         1350
2000    100-B   1           150         1350    
2000    200-A   2           900         1350
3000    200-A   1           450         450
```

Comment: well, what's your DBMS? SQL is just a query language, and each DBMS has its own dialects. And can you express what the exact logic for ORDERNET column's computation is ..?

Comment: what is wrong with your SQL - it is returning data for Order starts with 100 or 200. just replace it with 300 - `(od.prodcode like '300-%')`. Can you pls add more details for -   'sum based on specific content'

Comment: Sorry, I'll explain a bit better.
For instance the order 1000 can containt products 100-A, 100-B and 100-C but also 300-A etc. I only want to sum products that start with 100- or 200- per order.

Comment: The query gives you everything and on top of that you just need `ORDERNET` which gives you a sum per `ORDERNO`. Am I right ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, that's correct

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan I use Interbase Expert

Comment: @Patrik, did it not work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from the expected output ,use `sum` as window function to get it,

```
select om.orderno
      ,od.product
      ,od.preorderqty
      ,(od.preorderqty * od.nto) as preordernet
      ,sum(od.preorderqty * od.nto) over (partition by om.orderno) as ordernet
  from OrderMaster om
  join OrderDetail od 
    on od.orderid = om.id
     and ((od.prodcode like '100-%') 
       or (od.prodcode like '200-%'))
order by om.orderno,sod.prodcode
```

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't get it working with that. I just got an error 
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104. 
Token unknown over.

Comment: This is standard SQL and I have no clue why it's not working . And I don't know `Interbase Expert`. Does it not support window function ? If not I would like to delete my post

Comment: Ahh there was a paranthesis missing. I updated my answer. Could you try now?

Comment: @Patrik, any luck for you with you after I updated my answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Sujitmohanty30